# gparted says driver descriptor and Linux disagree on physical block size of a pen drive; drive does not automount; how to resolve?

Tags: usb-drive

On opening GParted, it says:

> The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes.

Also, it does not auto-mount when I plug it in.

How should I resolve this pen drive problem?

Comment: I believe this is a bug. See [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/781223/physical-block-size-is-2048-bytes-but-linux-says-it-is-512-when-formatting-a/781236#781236) on Ask Ubuntu

Answer (score 5):

I used [this command](http://flux.ninja/2016/03/fixing-usb-drive-block-size.html) and it fixed the problem:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/<id_of_your_device> bs=2048; sync
```

Usually, `<id_of_your_device>` is `sdb`, but make sure you check that, because if you use `sda` and it turns out to be your hard disk, all the data on your hard disk will get erased.

Answer (score 0):

if you have no data to be saved in the pen driver can place, simply you try to create a new partition table and then add the partition with the file system you want (you can also do it gparted )

Comment: Gparted did respond with error regarding differences in block size according to the drive and linux system.Anyways, the problem is resolved, as I made drive bootable with dd and set bs=2048.