# Warning: The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes

Tags: partition, lvm, ext4

My laptop has Lubuntu 18.04 installed, and I boot into a live Lubuntu via a bootable flash drive, and then examine the partitions and filesystems.

Is the following warning some serious problem to solve: "Warning: The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but
Linux says it is 512 bytes"?

What does it mean? Is it a problem about disks, partitions, file systems, or logical volumes?

What shall I do with it? Thanks.

```
$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABF0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB  fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   500GB  500GB                                     lvm


Warning: The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but
Linux says it is 512 bytes.
Ignore/Cancel?                                                            
Ignore/Cancel? I                                                          
Model: General UDisk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 16.1GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 2048B/512B
Partition Table: mac
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name   Flags
 1      2048B   6143B   4096B                Apple
 2      6222kB  8614kB  2392kB               EFI


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-root: 499GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  499GB  499GB  ext4


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-swap_1: 1028MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  1028MB  1028MB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: Unknown (unknown)
Disk /dev/zram3: 444MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  444MB  444MB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: Unknown (unknown)
Disk /dev/zram1: 444MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  444MB  444MB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: Unknown (unknown)
Disk /dev/zram2: 444MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  444MB  444MB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: Unknown (unknown)
Disk /dev/zram0: 444MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  444MB  444MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

Comment: The only devices that I'm familiar with that have 2048-byte sector size is CDROM devices. Maybe this is an artifact of how the live image was created?  In any case, if the filesystem is read-only it doesn't matter what the sector size is.

Comment: Sometimes making a USB disk into liveUSB, especially in an not supported way, cause buggy behavior. You might want to check  `udevadm info --name=/dev/sdb -a`

Comment: @LustreOne Why "if the filesystem is read-only it doesn't matter what the sector size is"?

Answer (score 2):

Here are two methods which both worked for me:

The simplest method for Linux is to begin with "Disk" and then finish with "gParted" https://askubuntu.com/a/915821/520965

The other simple method in Linux' terminal: https://superuser.com/a/1153220/601553 or https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/338883/184608